# Any way to get an official version of windows after harddrive failure?

Tags: windows-7

I have a laptop that used to have windows installed but the HD crashed. Is there any way to obtain the serial/in some other way download and install a legal version of windows? I have access to the microsoft account that was linked to this laptop.

if anything is unclear ffeel free to post a comment.

Comment: What's the model of the laptop?

Comment: Is the HD completely dead, I mean can it be read externally? If so use nirsoft to retrieve the serial key. http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/product_cd_key_viewer.html

Comment: If your laptop had a valid copy of Windows to begin with, then there should be a COA sticker (with a product key) on the bottom of the laptop.

Comment: True for windows 7. Windows 8 will pick up the key from the bios. And yeah, sticker key would work - not sure if you can use OEM keys to download media straight from MS tho

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways, the two primary was would be to call the support line for the manufacture of your laptop (Dell, HP, Acer, Lenovo, IBM, etc.) and have recovery disks sent to you, this may cost though. The other main way is if you have a CoA on the laptop that lists the key code you can just google for an OEM image of Windows for your maker i.e. "HP Windows 7 OEM) and download, burn, install from there.

Comment: I think the original installation was not windows 7 (it's a dell, has a windows xp sticker). The windows 7 was a later addition.

Comment: The same things stand, I presumed Windows 7 because of the tag. If you don't have the upgrade CD then you would only be able to reinstall to the original OS, probably XP.

Comment: Who added Windows7 later and where is the installation disc and the key.